# Error fetching OAuth credentials: "OAuthException: This authorization code has been used."

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, authentication, oauth

I have found many tutorials about this issue. But no one of them solved my problem. So, i'm trying on Symfony 4 to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) for OAuth2 Facebook

When i click on my button "Connexion with Facebook", i have a blank page with the message :

> Error fetching OAuth credentials: "OAuthException: This authorization
>   code has been used.".

I saw on some tutorials that is a problem about accessToken, longliveAccessToken, etc.

But i have no idea what to do in my code to solve this issue.

Here is my code of my FacebookAuthenticator.php :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User; // your user entity
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\Provider\FacebookClient;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class FacebookAuthenticator extends SocialAuthenticator
{
    private $clientRegistry;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        // continue ONLY if the current ROUTE matches the check ROUTE
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_facebook_check';
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        // this method is only called if supports() returns true

        // For Symfony lower than 3.4 the supports method need to be called manually here:
        // if (!$this->supports($request)) {
        //     return null;
        // }

        return $this->fetchAccessToken($this->getFacebookClient());
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        /** @var FacebookUser $facebookUser */
        $facebookUser = $this->getFacebookClient()
            ->fetchUserFromToken($credentials);


        // 1) have they logged in with Facebook before? Easy!
        $existingUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['facebookId' => $facebookUser->getId()]);
        if ($existingUser) {
            return $existingUser;
        }

        // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

        // 3) Maybe you just want to "register" them by creating
        // a User object
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*_";

        if(!$user){
        $user = new User();
        }
        $user->setFacebookId($facebookUser->getId());
        $user->setUsername($facebookUser->getEmail());
        $user->setPassword(password_hash(substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, 10), PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
        $user->setPrenom($facebookUser->getFirstName());
        $user->setNom($facebookUser->getLastName());
        $user->setEmail($facebookUser->getEmail());
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setSocialAuthentication(true);
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();


        return $user;

    }

    /**
     * @return FacebookClient
     */
    private function getFacebookClient()
    {

        return $this->clientRegistry
            // "facebook_main" is the key used in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
            ->getClient('facebook_main');
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        // on success, let the request continue
        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent.
     * This redirects to the 'login'.
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/connect/', // might be the site, where users choose their oauth provider
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }


}
```

My user is created in my database, with correct data, but can't authenticate with it.

Thanks for help me, if you want the code for FacebookController.php , tell me, then i will edit my post.

EDIT :

[image]

EDIT 2 :

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        /** @var FacebookUser $facebookUser */

        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('facebook_main');
        $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
        if ($accessToken && !$accessToken->getToken()) {
            dump("User is not found!"); die;
        }
        $provider = $client->getOAuth2Provider();
        $longLivedToken = $provider->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
        //I get the user by using long lived token
        $facebookUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($longLivedToken);

        $email = $facebookUser->getEmail();

        // 1) have they logged in with Facebook before? Easy!
        $existingUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['facebookId' => $facebookUser->getId()]);
        if ($existingUser) {
            return $existingUser;
        }

        // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

        // 3) Maybe you just want to "register" them by creating
        // a User object
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*_";

        if(!$user) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFacebookId($facebookUser->getId());
            $user->setUsername($facebookUser->getEmail());
            $user->setPassword(password_hash(substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 10), PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
            $user->setPrenom($facebookUser->getFirstName());
            $user->setNom($facebookUser->getLastName());
            $user->setEmail($facebookUser->getEmail());
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $user->setSocialAuthentication(true);
        }
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();


        return $user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem and I've refered the long live access token with this way. It might be a solution. Here you are.

```
$client = $clientRegistry->getClient('facebook_main');
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
if ($accessToken && !$accessToken->getToken()) {
    dump("User is not found!"); die;
}
$provider = $client->getOAuth2Provider();
$longLivedToken = $provider->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
//I get the user by using long lived token
$facebookUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($longLivedToken);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I have tried your code in the Facebook Controller, but i haven't "$facebookUser" used in this class. I have put this part of code in the connectCheckAction, is that right ?

Comment: It should be in FacebookAuthenticator class. As I recall.

Comment: Hi Mert, i have put your part of code in FacebookAuthenticator, in the getUser method as i have put in my edit 2, still didn't work, i have the same message. Thanks for your help bro.

Answer (score 0):

The first error you have:

> Error fetching OAuth credentials: "OAuthException: This authorization code has been used.".

Thats because you reload your Page (after e.g. change Code and refresh). The Error Message said that the Auth Code in Url Params used before.
Instead refresh your Site 1. go Back to the site where your button is placed and 2. get a new Auth Code by Clicking the FB Login Button.

Now this error is gone and you can go forward to debug your code.